# Is there any quick method to solve this second-order semilinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this second-order semilinear ODE
$$ x''(s)-3x(s) x'(s)+x^3(s)=0, ~s\in\mathbb{R}.$$
I have tried this substitution 
$$p(x)=x'(s),$$ which implies $$x''(s)=p(x)\frac{d p(x)}{dx},$$ with which I reduced the original ODE to a first-order nonlinear non-homogeneous ODE. But this method is too clumsy.  Is there any quick solver?

Maple has given the solution as $$x \left( s \right) ={\frac {-2\,{ C_1}\,s-2\,{C_2}}{{ C_1
}\,{s}^{2}+2\,{ C_2}\,s+2}},
$$
and I am very curious of how do Maple solve?

Comment: wolfram alpha has a different answer. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y''-3yy'%2By%5E3+%3D+0

Comment: maybe that is what you meant and don't know $\TeX$. should I edit?

Comment: Yeah it is okay now.

Comment: Sorry, I have just convert Maple's result into LaTeX directly, without considering the convention. I have modified Maple's solution.

Comment: yeah it is okay now.

Comment: Simplifying the result given by Sabyasachi, I arrived to $$x(s)=-\frac{2 e^{\frac{2 c_1}{9}} \left(c_2+s\right)}{e^{\frac{2 c_1}{9}}
   \left(c_2+s\right){}^2+3}=-\frac{2 c_1 \left(c_2+s\right)}{c_1 \left(c_2+s\right){}^2+3}$$ which, I suppose, makes the agreement between Maple and Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @azhi: how did you get a linear nonhomogeneous equation? According to the above substitution the transformed eqution becomes $pp'-3xp+x^3=0$, which is obviously not linear.

Comment: The substitution shown transforms the original ODE into an Abel equation of the second kind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homogeneous EDO is successively transformed to homogeneous then separable EDO as shown below :

[image]

Comment: I get $t=1-\frac{c_1}{X}\pm\sqrt{\dots}$

Comment: That sign error in the quadratic formula for $t$ gets carried through to $x$. Just flip the sign of $x$ and the solution is OK.